# Length of projection of vector $v$ to $u$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u$ be a unit vector in $n$ dimensional space. If I have another vector $v$ and want to project it on a line parallel to vector $u$, what is the formula for calculating the distance between point of projection and the origin?

The only thing I've managed to find is that it's equal to dot product $u \cdot v$ or equivalently $u^T v$, but I don't why that is. How to justify it?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Scalar_projection_and_first_properties).

Comment: OK, but the geometrical interpretation of dot product only works in 2D. What about higher dimensions? In 2D, we understand what we mean by projection of A onto some other vector (it's just cosine of the angle between two vectors times length of A) - it's equivalent to dot product (in this specific 2D case). But it tells us nothing about higher dimensions

Comment: @user216094 It's just the 2d case applied to the plane spanned by the two vectors.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, the geometric interpretation of the dot product works well in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I want to sum here this result.

We have two vectors $\mathbf{v}= v_1\mathbf{e_1}+v_2\mathbf{e_2}$ and $\mathbf{u}= u_1\mathbf{e_1}+u_2\mathbf{e_2}$ and, being $\{\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2}\}$ the canonical basis we know that: 
$$
v_1=|\mathbf{v}|\cos \alpha \quad v_2=|\mathbf{v}|\sin \alpha
$$
and

$$
u_1=|\mathbf{u}|\cos \beta \quad u_2=|\mathbf{u}|\sin \beta
$$

where $\alpha, \beta$ are the angles between $\mathbf{e_1}$ and the two vectors.

Now we **define** :

$\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}=|\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|\cos\theta$

where $\theta=\beta-\alpha$ is the angle between two vectors. Using trigonometry we find:
$$
|\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|\cos(\beta-\alpha)=|\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|(\cos \alpha \cos \beta+\sin\alpha \sin \beta)=
$$
$$
=(|\mathbf{v}|\cos \alpha) (|\mathbf{u}|\cos\beta)+(|\mathbf{v}|\sin \alpha)(|\mathbf{u}|\sin \beta)=
$$
$$
=u_1v_1+u_2v_2
$$

This is fine and give us the machinery to find angles between vectors an to project  a vector over an other vector using the components.

Generalize this result to any Hilbert space is not so simple, and we have to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that states:

$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^n{x_iy_i} \right|^2\le\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i^2}\sum_{i=1}^n{y_i^2}  
$$

So, given $\mathbf{x}=\sum_{i=1}{x_i\mathbf{e_i}}$ and $\mathbf{y}=\sum_{i=1}{y_i\mathbf{e_i}}$ we can **define** the dot product as:
$$
\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}=\sum_{i=1}{x_i y_i}
$$
and we have:
$
\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}\le ||\mathbf{x}||\; ||\mathbf{y}||
$
So we see that there exists an angle $\theta$ such that

$$
\cos \theta = \dfrac{\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}}{ ||\mathbf{x}||\; ||\mathbf{y}||}
$$
and we can **define** such $\theta$ as the angle between the two vectors.

And , finally, from this we have an analogy with the $\mathbb{R}^2$ situation ad we can find the prjection of a vector on another one.( And this work also for infinite dimensional Hilbet spaces).

Comment: In the 2D example, what if we project $v$ to $u$ and obtain vector $v_p$ whose length is greater that $u$? Is it possible? It's quite counterintuitive - we're projecting on a vector and the projection doesn't lie on that vector...

Comment: It's possible. We are projecting on the **direction** of $u$ i.e. the subspace spanned by $u$, non properly on  $u$.

Answer (score 2):

In general: $${\rm proj}_{\bf u}{\bf v} = \frac{{\bf u}\cdot {\bf v}}{{\bf u}\cdot{\bf u}}{\bf u}.$$ Here $\|{\bf u}\| = 1$, so ${\bf u}\cdot {\bf u} = 1$ and we have ${\rm proj}_{\bf u}{\bf v} = ({\bf u}\cdot{\bf v}){\bf u}$. Hence the distance to the origin is: $$\|{\rm proj}_{\bf u}{\bf v} - {\bf 0}\| = \|{\rm proj}_{\bf u}{\bf v}\| = \|({\bf u}\cdot{\bf v}){\bf u}\| = |{\bf u}\cdot{\bf v}|\|{\bf u}\| = |{\bf u}\cdot{\bf v}|.$$

Comment: ${\rm proj}_{\bf u}{\bf v} = \frac{{\bf u}\cdot {\bf v}}{{\bf u}\cdot{\bf u}}{\bf u}.$ Why is projection defined that way?

Comment: It is motivated by $\Bbb R^2$: draw two vectors ${\bf u}$ and $\bf v$ starting at the origin, the line $\ell$ passing through $\bf u$, and the line perpendicular to $\ell$ passing through the head of $\bf v$. If you compute the intersection, you will get that expression.

Answer (score 2):

Say the length of projection is $l$, then the projection vector is $l\mathrm{u}$

[image]

Next notice that $\mathrm{u}$ is perpendicular to $\mathrm{v}-l\mathrm{u}$, therefore the dot product has to be $0$
$$\mathrm{u}^T(\mathrm{v}-l\mathrm{u}) = 0 $$

Solving for $l$ we get
$$l = \dfrac{\mathrm{u}^T\mathrm{v}}{\mathrm{u}^T\mathrm{u}}$$

as desired.